# YUM Package Depends on uname -m or uname -i

Tags: yum

I have been trying to install libstdc++ packages using yum thru shell script in my customer's machines. I need to confirm whether yum will list i686 or i386 package in user machine, i mean will yum check for 'uname -p' - processor info or 'uname -i' - hardware platform ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i have Checked , yum seems to be depeneds on processor architecture, uname -p.